# Series expansion of {x}

Tags: summation, fourier-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Hello and sorry for my bad English. I am not mathematician, so sorry if this seems a silly question.
I've seen this formula regarding the fractional part of a number in Wikipedia, and I would like to prove it and know why does that happen.
$$\{x\} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2k\pi x)}{k}$$
[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) is the original link. Thank you very much

Comment: What's your background? Because if you know the theory of Fourier series, this is a routine calculation to find these coefficients. For example see $a_n,b_n$ at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition

Comment: You need read page 1, and the first paragraphs of page 2 from the lecture notes of the professor Victor H. Moll, *THE EXPANSION OF BERNOULLI POLYNOMIALS IN FOURIER SERIES*, from Tulane University. That is (14), then I believe that from this (14) your identity is easily deduced if there are no mistakes in my reasoning, when one identifties $ \left\{ x \right\} =x$ on $0<x<1$, combined with $$\sin \left( 2\pi n \left( x -\frac{1}{2}\right)  \right)=(-1)^n\sin \left(2 \pi n x \right).  $$ Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to plot a graph of the fractional part of $x$ against $x$, you would get essentially a "sawtooth wave", as the fractional part starts at 0 (when $x$ is an integer) and increases linearly to just below 1, until just before the next integer (where the 1 will 'wrap around' to become 0 again). Try plotting this function, either a sketch by hand or use some graphing software.
You will see (and I won't prove it here) that $f(x)=\{x\}$ is a periodic function with period 1 (that is it repeats every 1 unit on the $x$-axis). Because of this property it is expressible as a Fourier series. If you were to shift the $x$-axis up by 1/2 a unit, you would have an odd function, which would mean you would only get sine terms in the Fourier series. So, in your formula, the 1/2 comes from the shift of the horizontal axis, and the sine terms constitute the Fourier sine series for the resulting function.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sttbnrujqm